# How to readline in Mocha/Chai test to test data

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have large CSV files that I want to parse and check values eg UUIDs, not nulls, lengths etc. I know there is some validation in some of the CSV parsers like fast-csv but not everything, so I am creating a test suite using Mocha/Chai combined with Validator.js.

However as I want to read the data line by line and do multiple tests on each value I am struggling to define my tests. This first code snippet works as the readline is within the 'it' function.

```
describe('Each row should validate', function() {
            it('validate', function(done) {
                const rl = readline.createInterface({
                    input: fs.createReadStream('file path'),
                    crlfDelay: Infinity
                });
                let lineCount = 0
              
                rl.on('line', (line) => {
                    lineCount++
                    if(lineCount > 1) {
                        expect(validator.isUUID(line.split(',')[0]), `Line Number:${lineCount} is incorrect`).to.equal(true)
                    }
                });
                rl.on('close', function (line) {
                    done();
                });
            })
        });
```

However what I would like is to have multiple 'it' tests against each line when I add those in then no tests are run at all.

```
describe('Each row should validate', function() {
            const rl = readline.createInterface({
                input: fs.createReadStream(product.sourcefile),
                crlfDelay: Infinity
            });
            let lineCount = 0            
            rl.on('line', (line) => {
                lineCount++
                if(lineCount > 1) {
                    it('Should be a UUID', function() {
                        
                        expect(validator.isUUID(line.split(',')[0]), `Line Number:${lineCount} is incorrect`).to.equal(true)
                    })
                    it('Should not be null', function() {
                        expect(validator.isEmpty(line.split(',')[0]), `Line Number:${lineCount} ID is missing`).to.equal(false)
                    })
                }
            });
        });
```

Can anyone recommend a better way or fix the above?

Using NodeJS on Windows 10.